# Find subset of points whose distance among each other is a multiple of a number

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

The problem: given an array `A` which represents points on a line, e.g. `[5,-4,1,3,6]`, and a number `M=3`, find the maximal subset of points within `A` whose distance among each other is a multiple of `M`.

In the example, the two possible subsets would be `[-4,5]` (distance 9) and `[3,6]` (distance 3).

The obvious brute force solution would be to compute the distance between each pair of points in `O(N^2)` time, then build a set of candidates by incrementally building up the subsets.

Is there a more efficient solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iterate over the numbers in the array and compute the modulus M of each, and group by the result. The largest group is the maximal subset.

e.g. `[5,-4,1,3,6]` would give `[2,2,1,0,0]`

You'd have to take care how you handle negative numbers, the modulus operation for negatives is defined [differently in some languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Remainder_calculation_for_the_modulo_operation) (e.g. PHP) to others, but you would want mod(-4, 3) to evaluate to 2, not -1. For negatives you could compute it as (M - (-x mod M)) mod M

You could efficiently group the numbers by storing a hash map of lists containing the numbers, keyed on the modulus.

Comment: Ah, so simple, thanks! Altough I still don't quite understand why negative numbers need to be handled differently

Comment: It just depends on how the modulus operation works in whatever language you use. It's more of a tricky implementation detail to watch out for rather than part of the algorithm I guess.